# Matlab returns empty symbol when solving laplace transform

Tags: matlab

I have a laplace equation defined in matlab that I believe to be correct. It is defined as eqnLT

```matlab
% R1, R2, C1, C2 are positive symbols
% i(t) is a symbolic function

eqn(t) =
 
0 == R1*i(t) + R2*i(t) + diff(i(t), t)/10 + int(i(t), t)/C1 + int(i(t), t)/C2

eqnLT = laplace(eqn, t, s) =
 
0 == (s*laplace(i(t), t, s))/10 - i(0)/10 + laplace(int(i(t), t), t, s)/C1 + laplace(int(i(t), t), t, s)/C2 + R1*laplace(i(t), t, s) + R2*laplace(i(t), t, s)
```

I want to solve for `laplace(i(t), t, s)` let it be called `I(s)`. Following the instructions I can find in the matlab documentation, I do the following:

```matlab
subs(eqnLT, laplace(i(t),t,s),I(s)));
solve(eqnLT, I(s))
```

The answer I get is `empty sym`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I needed to use just `I` instead of `I(s)` and I needed to substitute `laplace(int(i(t),t,s)` with `I/s` explicitly. Then I was able to solve simplify and inverse laplace without issue.